# How to grep elements in array that match patterns from another array?

Tags: ruby, regex, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
a = ["X2", "X3/X4", "X5/X6/X7", "X8/X9/X10/X11"]
b = ["X9/X10", "X3/X4"]
```

Now I need to select entries from 'a' array which regexp with any of entries from array 'b'.

Expected result is:

```
["X3/X4", "X8/X9/X10/X11"]
```

How can I do this in Ruby?

Answer (score 4):

I'd do:

```
a.grep(Regexp.union(b))
# => ["X3/X4", "X8/X9/X10/X11"]
```

Comment: TypeError: can't convert Array into String
        from (irb):281:in `union'

Comment: @user2562153 What Ruby version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
a.grep(/#{b.join('|')}/)
# => ["X3/X4", "X8/X9/X10/X11"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the below:

```
 a = ["X2", "X3/X4", "X5/X6/X7", "X8/X9/X10/X11"] 
 b = ["X9/X10", "X3/X4"]
 p a.select{|i| b.any?{|j| i.include? j }}
 #>> ["X3/X4", "X8/X9/X10/X11"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The safest way is to build a regular expression and then select elements of your array matching this expression:

```
Regexp.union("a", "b", "c")
# => /a|b|c/

Regexp.union(["a", "b", "c"])
# => /a|b|c/

("b".."e").to_a.grep(Regexp.union("a", "b", "c"))
# => ["b", "c"]
```

Comment: Code-only answers do very little to educate SO readers.  Your answer may or may not be a correct answer, but it is in the moderation queue after being marked as "low-quality".  Please take a moment to improve your answer with an explanation.